# Weird browsersync behaviour when using child routers in aurelia with pushstate activated

Tags: aurelia, browser-sync, html5-history

I have enabled pushState on my aurelia routers, and set a root.

```
config.options.pushState = true;
config.options.root = '/vNext';
```

I have set a base href in my head:

```
<head>
    <base href="/vNext/" />
```

In my page I nest a child router, which contains a redirect from "" to list

**app.ts:**

```
config.map([
  { route: '', redirect: 'child-router-1' }, ...
```

**child-router-1.ts:**

```
 config.map([
      { route: '', redirect: 'list' }, ...
```

**What works**

- Reload works, when changing a file all browser windows correctly reload with the change.
- Browser sync: Syncing clicks on non-link elements (e.g. collapsing menu) works, I can click in one window and it will have effect in all browser-synced windows

**What doesn't work**

- Browser Sync: Syncing navigation after clicking a link (top level or child level routes all have this problem).  Here only the clicked window navigates to the link. But all other browser-sync connected windows either
  stay on the current page, or wrongly navigate to the child-router url
  instead of the linked routed.

e.g. when in */vNext/child-router1/* list clicking on a link to  */vNext/child-router1/5000/detail*  would have no effect in connected browsers, even though the socket.io fragments show a click.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this merged pull request
which enhances pushstate support for browser sync

https://github.com/aurelia/cli/pull/204/files

Comment: Looking at the date from that PR, I would expect it to have already been in there when I made this stackoverflow post. I'll keep an eye on it, and update if needed.

Comment: I've seen somewhere else a recommendation to just modify the task yourself. You can check them in aurelia_project/tasks folder